# Sending a Mime Part attachment via Axis2

Tags: java, apache-axis, mime

I have a web service whose WSDL and XSD make no reference to SWARef, mime or MTOM. The developer of the web service has told me to send him an attachment as a "mime part".

My client is auto-generated, a subclass of `org.apache.axis2.client.Stub`.

Nothing in the generated methods nor classes will accept binary data (ie no `DataHandler`, etc)

Is there a way to modify the request so that the attachment can be sent?

Does the databinding make any difference? We are using `xmlbeans` here.